# Androidの端末ごとの解像度

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Unity Remote 4でAndroidで実機再生しましたが、Unityでは画面は横長だったのに
Androidでは縦長になっています。その際、画面が横幅縮小され解像度が下がるのですが
これは実機再生しながら調整するのが好ましいということですか？
また、Androidの端末によって解像度、API？も違うのでそれぞれの端末に合わせる方法
はありますか？

また大きいサイズ（769×1000)のような画像を解像度を落とさずに小さく表示するには
カメラの位置を移動する必要がありますか？

Answer (score 3):

Unity Remote 4はGameViewの画面を端末に転送します。なので、横長の画面を縦長の端末へ転送すると端末が縦長になります。なので横長の画面をUnity Remoteで再生したい場合は、端末を回して横長にする必要があると思います。
基本的にGameViewの解像度を引き延ばすので、レイアウトを確認したい場合はGameViewも端末のレイアウト（解像度ではなくアスペクト比）と同じものにするか、端末へ転送するのが良い気がします。

Comment: 横長の画面を再生したいのではなく、実機で再生される、縦長の画面を
gameviewでも確認し調整したいのですが、gameviewを縦長にする方法
はありますでしょうか

Answer (score 2):

僕の方では UI のButtonが画面にあるとして、そのButtonの幅がある割合(表示幅の50%)になるように解像度を変更する、という自作のスクリプトを用意しています。

[ScreenSizeKeeper.cs](https://github.com/yasokada/unity-150825-TELChecker/blob/master/Assets/ScreenSizeKeeper.cs)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScreenSizeKeeper : MonoBehaviour {

    public Button myButton; // set UI>Button whose width is used as standard

    bool isRunningOnAndroid() {
        return (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android);
    }

    void Start () {
        if (isRunningOnAndroid () == false) {
            return;
        }
        float aspect = (float)Screen.height / (float)Screen.width;
        float buttonRatio = 0.5f; // 50%
        int buttonWidth = (int)myButton.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().rect.width;
        float newWidth, newHeight;

        newWidth = buttonWidth / buttonRatio;
        newHeight = newWidth * aspect;

        Screen.SetResolution ((int)newWidth, (int)newHeight, false);
    }   
}
```

上記スクリプトをEmptyなGameObject(名前: ScreenSizeKeeper)に関連付けして画面解像度を調整しています。

VerticalとHorizontalの切替は考慮されていません。